# WordPress минификация файлов

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть список подключенных js файлов, необходимо собрать их все и как-то минифицировать. Как лучше сделать? Ведь все в один файл пихать не комильфо, я думал отдельно либы минифицированные подключить, а потом все собственные скрипты в один файл запихать. Какие есть способы посоветуете, господа? Как будет правильнее? Может, хорошие плагины-оптимизаторы есть на WP?

Comment: Лучше этого не делать. Профита никакого, а проблем выше крыши.

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и сделаю, ибо разницы не почувствовал действительно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и до `yarn` добраться. Но самый простой способ - плагин [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/).